# Error in attribute creation and reference Python classes multilevel inheritance

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I have the following program that seeks to demonstrate multilevel inheritance. Unfortunately on calling `m2` and the `eligible_for_reward` method, I am getting the following:

```
m2=Marks()
m2.eligible_for_reward()
```

Error:

```
Marks has no attribute totalmarks
```

The code is below:

```
# Define a class as 'student'
class Student:
    # Method
    def getStudent(self):
        self.name = input("Name: ")
        self.age = input("Age: ")
        self.gender = input("Gender: ")

#The Test Class inherits from the Student Class.
class Test(Student):
    # Method
    def getMarks(self):
        self.stuClass = input("YearGroup/Class: ")
        print("Enter the marks of the respective subjects")
        self.literature = int(input("Literature: "))
        self.math = int(input("Math: "))
        self.biology = int(input("Biology: "))
        self.physics = int(input("Physics: "))

# Note that the Marks Class inherits from the Test Class and in doing so inherits from the Student Class
class Marks(Test):    
    # Method
    def display(self):
        print("\n\nName: ",self.name)
        print("Age: ",self.age)
        print("Gender: ",self.gender)
        print("Class Year Group: ",self.stuClass)
        self.totalmarks=self.literature+self.math+self.biology+self.physics
        print("Total Marks: ", self.literature + self.math + self.biology + self.physics)

    def eligible_for_reward(self):
        if self.totalmarks>=90 and self.age>13:
            print("You are eligible for the fabulous school sponsored trip to London")
        else:
            print("Sorry, you are not eligible and so are going nowhere....!")
```

UPDATE:

I also tried the following, that is definig self.totalmarks in the relevant method, but that also came up with an error:**name 'totalmarks' is not defined**

```
def eligible_for_reward(self):
        self.totalmarks=totalmarks
        if self.totalmarks>=90 and self.age>13:
            print("You are eligible for the fabulous school sponsored trip to London")
        else:
            print("Sorry, you are not eligible and so are going nowhere....!")
```

Furthmore, I also tried

```
    m2=Marks()
    m2.display()
    m2.eligible_for_reward()
```

**and the error:**

```
AttributeError: 'Marks' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: You only set `totalmarks` when `Marks.display()` is called. You didn't call `Marks.display()`, so the attribute doesn't exist.

Comment: Many thanks. I tried that, as per the suggested answer below, but an error persists

Comment: So look at what attributes `display()` needs, and where those are set.

Comment: I can see that they are input by the user in the previous class, but am not sure how to declare them again in the new class/method. That's what I need help and direction with! In the Marks Class, can I simply initialise the attributes in a __init__ ...such as self.literature = etc.

Comment: self.lliterature, self.math, etc should be super().literature, super().math, etc and you must initialize super() class inside __init__() function of the child class.

Comment: @Abhijeetk431 could you possibly post this as an answer with my original code fixed. It is not obvious from your coment what to do, and where

Comment: As I see this, there is no need for 3 classes at all. If a student just gets one mark per subject, you could just fit everything in the student class. Quite apart from that, a Subclass Marks from Test makes no sense to me as well as subclassing student with a class Test is just kind of nonsense.

Comment: Totally unrelated but your inheritance tree is (from a design POV) completely wrong.  Inheritance is semantically a "is a" relationship (if B inherit from A, then B is a A). It should be obvious that a Mark is not a Test and that neither are a Student... The relationships you want to describe here are "has a" (or "has many") relationships, which are implemented by aggregation.

Comment: @Bruno - that is a really helpful comment. Do you have any suggestions as to how to set it up to demonstrate multilevel inheritance for teaching/learning purposes. Also, isn't it possible to have classes that you inherit from that are totally unrelated. e.g. ClassStudent and ClassScores....This is the first I've heard that it ALWAYS has to be a is-a relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define attribute `self.totalmarks` in `display()` method of `Marks` class

So when you call eligible_for_reward(), totalmarks is not defined at this moment. So you can fix this by calling display() method first:

```
m2=Marks()
m2.dispay()
m2.eligible_for_reward()
```

But this won't work because 
`self.literature` `self.math` `self.biology` `self.physics` are not defined at this time as well.

You have to add **init**() method to all the classes to call super() inside and correctly instantiate the class, like this:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = input("Name: ")
        self.age = input("Age: ")
        self.gender = input("Gender: ")

class Test(Student):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Test, self).__init__()
        self.stuClass = input("YearGroup/Class: ")
        print("Enter the marks of the respective subjects")
        self.literature = int(input("Literature: "))
        self.math = int(input("Math: "))
        self.biology = int(input("Biology: "))
        self.physics = int(input("Physics: "))

class Marks(Test):    
    def __init__(self):
        super(Marks, self).__init__()
        self.total_marks = self.literature + self.math + self.biology + self.physics

    def display(self):
        print("\n\nName: ",self.name)
        print("Age: ",self.age)
        print("Gender: ",self.gender)
        print("Class Year Group: ",self.stuClass)

        print("Total Marks: ", self.literature + self.math + self.biology + self.physics)

    def eligible_for_reward(self):
        if self.total_marks>=90 and self.age>13:
            print("You are eligible for the fabulous school sponsored trip to London")
        else:
            print("Sorry, you are not eligible and so are going nowhere....!")
```

And you can use it as follow:

```
marks = Marks()
marks.eligible_for_reward()
marks.display()
```

Comment: I'd like ideally to define it correctly so I don't have to call the display method first. How is this done?See my edit

Comment: Also, with your solution, I now get this error: AttributeError: 'Marks' object has no attribute 'name'. The solution needs to explain how best to implement this so it DOES work!

Comment: Note that `display()` uses attributes *other* methods have set. You can't just tell them to run `display()` only.

Comment: Thank you Alexey - I will try that in a minute. Could you add to your answer, what precisely the "super" part does. I did not think you needed to explicitly use 'super' when the Class has been created extending/inheriting from the super class anyway.....this is not clear to me.

Comment: `super()` calls `__init__()` method of parent class

Comment: So super(Test, self).__init__() calls the method of itself (Test) or of the Parent class? wouldn't it make sense then for it to be super(Student), self).__init__() instead of super(Test, self).__init__()

Comment: In super() method you should pass name of current class. So  `super(Test, self).__init__()` will call `__init__()` of parent of Test class

Comment: That's not intuitive at all. Thank you!

Comment: I'd move the `input()` calls *out* of the classes. You want to be able to create such a class from different sources, not just user input.

Comment: @MissComputing you can think about `super(Test, self).__init__()` like super of Test or parent of Test.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment I don't see a reason for the way you are subclassing. So I put it together as one class Student like this:

```
class Student:
    # Method
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = input("Name: ")
        self.age = int(input("Age: "))
        self.gender = input("Gender: ")

    def setMarks(self):
         self.stuClass = input("YearGroup/Class: ")
         print("Enter the marks of the respective subjects")
         self.literature = int(input("Literature: "))
         self.math = int(input("Math: "))
         self.biology = int(input("Biology: "))
         self.physics = int(input("Physics: "))
         self.totalmarks=self.literature+self.math+self.biology+self.physics

    def display(self):
         print("\n\nName: ",self.name)
         print("Age: ",self.age)
         print("Gender: ",self.gender)
         print("Class Year Group: ",self.stuClass)
         self.totalmarks=self.literature+self.math+self.biology+self.physics
         print("Total Marks: ", self.literature + self.math + self.biology + self.physics)

    def eligible_for_reward(self):
         if self.totalmarks>=90 and self.age>13:
             print("You are eligible for the fabulous school sponsored trip to London")
         else:
             print("Sorry, you are not eligible and so are going nowhere....!")
```

Example usage:

```
s1 = Student()
>>> Name: Hans
>>> Age: 17
>>> Gender: m
s1.setMarks()
>>> YearGroup/Class: 2017
>>> Enter the marks of the respective subjects
>>> Literature: 11
>>> Math: 14
>>> Biology: 42
>>> Physics: 10

s1.display()


>>> Name:  Hans
>>> Age:  17
>>> Gender:  m
>>> Class Year Group:  2017
>>> Total Marks:  77

s1.eligible_for_reward()
>>> Sorry, you are not eligible and so are going nowhere....!
```

Comment: I'm sub classing in order to demonstrate multil-level inheritance. Any suggestions as to how to demonstrate that with your answer. That's the main point of this task for me. Many thanks

Comment: Than try to go with subclassing Student with a class for Undergraduates, Graduates and so on. As bruno desthuilliers said in the comments, the relationship should be 'is a'. So Undergraduate is a Student. It inherits the standard attributes like name, age and so on. But could have additional fields and functions, that only Undergraduates got.

Comment: Okay. So it is literally a RULE that all class inherited relationships MUST be is-a. (e.g. IF B inherits from A, B is an A) ...? I never knew this. In game playing, don't players inherit from a score or world class? I'd be interested in clarification of this

Comment: Yes, that is actually the idea of inheritance. No, I don't think so, the player might have a Score-Property, which itself could be a class, but the Score would not be inheriting from the player.

Comment: But inheritance is about inheriting attributes as well as methods isn't it? e.g. a player could inherit the attributes of score, such as current_score or health. Isn't having a score property if that property is an attribute of another class, also an example of inheritance. That is how several tutorials seem to teach it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is working code with minimum edits, Hope this helps you :-

```
class Student:
    # Method
    def getStudent(self):
        self.name = input("Name: ")
        self.age = int(input("Age: "))
        self.gender = input("Gender: ")

#The Test Class inherits from the Student Class.
class Test(Student):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        super().getStudent()
    # Method
    def getMarks(self):
        self.stuClass = input("YearGroup/Class: ")
        print("Enter the marks of the respective subjects")
        self.literature = int(input("Literature: "))
        self.math = int(input("Math: "))
        self.biology = int(input("Biology: "))
        self.physics = int(input("Physics: "))

# Note that the Marks Class inherits from the Test Class and in doing so inherits from the Student Class
class Marks(Test):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        super().getMarks()
    # Method
    def display(self):
        print("\n\nName: ",self.name)
        print("Age: ",self.age)
        print("Gender: ",self.gender)
        print("Class Year Group: ",self.stuClass)
        self.totalmarks=self.literature+self.math+self.biology+self.physics
        print("Total Marks: ", self.literature + self.math + self.biology + self.physics)

    def eligible_for_reward(self):
        if self.totalmarks>=90 and self.age>13:
            print("You are eligible for the fabulous school sponsored trip to London")
        else:
            print("Sorry, you are not eligible and so are going nowhere....!")



mrk = Marks()
mrk.display()
mrk.eligible_for_reward()
```

Comment: Just added init function of super class and triggered some other functions that were necessary. Converted age to int and invoked display function to initialize totalmarks variable.